# How can I get 3d position data with arkit face tracking?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphics, arkit

I want to get (extract) 3d position data of my face with ARKit face tracking. (In detail I want to capture the scene and get 3d position data of my face with face tracking in captured scene.)
Is there any way to get 3d position data of the face which is tracked by ARKit?

What function should I use to get the 3d position data?

Answer (score -1):

If you need a 3D position of touch location in the screen, you can use hitTest method.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest